# working with a new Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `NewForm` and I need it to do something in my main form when a button in my new form is clicked.

```
    public Newform()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void dontsave_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I have a  `dontsave` button and I need it to clear my textbox in my mainform when clicked and close the newform.

Comment: You marked this question with a tag referring to html forms.  But your code looks to be a definition for Winforms.

Comment: "I have a save button and don't save button and both are going to do things in my main form." - Excellent!  That _is_ a start!  Now, phase two, ask us a question...

Comment: You need to pass the main form as a constructor parameter and call public functions.

Comment: Dude, come on?! What things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you started:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// Form1 code.
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      Form2 frm2 = new Form2();  // Instantiate your form2 object.
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         frm2.Show();  // Show the form.
      }

      private void button_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         SaveFileDialog saveDlg = new SaveFileDialog();
         saveDlg.ShowDialog();  // This shows a 'Save' dialog.

         if (saveDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)  // Capture user input from the dialog.
         {
            // do some work here
         }
      }

      private void dontsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        frm2.ClearTextBox(frm2); // Call the 'ClearTextBox' function from form2.
      }

      private void cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        this.Close(); // NOTE:  Probably better to use Application.Exit() here.
      }
   }
}    

//Form2 code.
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
   public partial class Form2 : Form
   {
      public Form2()
      {
         InitializeComponent();            
      }

      public void ClearTextBox(Form form) // Pass a form as an overload.
      {
         textBox1.Text = ""; // Clear the textbox.
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you create your NewForm, you need to either:

1) Create an overload constructor to accept your parent form
2) have a public property which holds a reference to your parent form then finally show your NewForm

then when you are pressing the "dontsave" - simply reference the parent form and clear the textbox, and making sure the textbox property is either public or much preferably, a method call (dont give full access to a UI Control from other forms!)

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend against blindly passing one Form into the constructor of another. Instead, expose some property events of the child form:

```
public Form1() {
   var childForm = new ChildForm();
   childForm.DontSave += // event handler
}

class ChildForm : Form {

   public event EventHandler DontSave {
      add { dontSaveButton.Click += value; }
      remove { dontSaveButton.Click -= value; }
   }

}
```

Comment: This is a _better_ answer than the one I provided - I was just trying to keep it simple for someone who appears to be a neophyte - +1.

Answer (score 1):

At MainForm.cs

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    NewForm frm2;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        frm2 = new NewForm();
        frm2.Show();
        frm2.dontSaveButton += new DontSaveButtonHandler(frm2_dontSaveButton);
    }

    void frm2_dontSaveButton()
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
        frm2.Close();

    }

}
```

At NewForm.cs

```
public delegate void DontSaveButtonHandler();

public partial class NewForm : Form
{
    public event DontSaveButtonHandler dontSaveButton;

    public NewForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnDontSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dontSaveButton != null)
        {
            dontSaveButton();
        }
    }
}
```

I would guess my answer is what supposed to be. Using delegate is a good practice.